# A question concerning Ulam's Theorem from Oxtoby's "Measure and Category"

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, definition, descriptive-set-theory, baire-category

I am reading the following theorem from Oxtoby's *Measure and Category*

> **Theorem 5.6 (Ulam).** A finite measure $\mu$ defined for all subsets of a
> set $X$ of power $\aleph_1$ *vanishes identically* if it is equal to zero for every one-element subset.

My question is: what does it mean for a set $A$, to vanish identically? I mean, identically to what?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: Note that the actual wording is *be a one-to-one mapping of this set onto a subset of the positive integers*. Specifically, note the presence of **a subset of**. As for *vanishes identically*, this just means that the measure is zero for every subset of the set (equivalently, by monotonicity of measure, the measure of the set is zero). By the way, what you have in quote marks (and imply as being a quote) does not appear in page image you showed.

Comment: Oh, i see.. I missed that, will remove this part of my question

Comment: Regarding the method of proof in Oxtoby's Theorem 5.6, you may find it helpful to google the phrase "Ulam matrix". In particular, look at what this article says about Ulam matrices (top of p. 446): [Ulam, the Man and the Mathematician](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1985-37.pdf) by Paul Erdős.

Comment: I will certainly take a look. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"What does it mean for a set $A$, to vanish identically?" --- It doesn't mean anything, but nothing in the material you quoted mentions a set vanishing identically. The closest it comes is in the statement of the theorem, where it refers to a measure $\mu$ vanishing identically.  That means that $\mu(S)=0$ for all $S$.  (Quite generally, a function vanishes identically if its value is $0$ for all inputs in its domain.)

Comment: Oh, The zero function.. ok thanks.